# How to generate qr code for multiple input string?

Tags: java, android

**I have implemented for one input string parameter I want to store mobile number,email id, first name,last name like multiple input string and generate qr code for same.I am new in android please help me for that.**
**here is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    EditText editText;


    String EditTextValue ;
    Thread thread ;
    public final static int QRcodeWidth = 500 ;
    Bitmap bitmap ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditTextValue = editText.getText().toString();

                try {
                    bitmap = TextToImageEncode(EditTextValue);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }


    Bitmap TextToImageEncode(String Value) throws WriterException {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix;
        try {
            bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
                    Value,
                    BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX.QR_CODE,
                    QRcodeWidth, QRcodeWidth, null
            );

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException Illegalargumentexception) {

            return null;
        }
        int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();

        int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();

        int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
            int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;

            for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {

                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ?
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeBlackColor):getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeWhiteColor);
            }
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 500, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: user zxing library to generate qr.